# Field shown in Template as None but has value in Datastore viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I got a super strange problem.

I got a table with a bunch of rows, all look perfectly fine in the Datastore viewer. But when I for loop over the data and output it in the template (using jinja2) for one row a few fields show up as None.

I had this problem earlier today, and got it working by pressing edit on the row in the Datastore Viewer, then pressing save without changing any data.

The data looks clean, it's just some strings and an integer, nothing odd about it.

Comment: What is the value that is shown in the Datastore viewer? It is possible to have issues with templating systems for values of 0, False etc. because they get evaluated to none if they don't explicitly check in the condition: "prop is not None"

Comment: One was a string, and it looked identical to the string in other rows. And the other was an integer (the nr. 3), nothing odd about .